# How to solve activity not found exception when navigate to other view?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am getting a Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: when I want to go to another activity.
Also I have to recreate my emulator every time I want to see my app because it causes always adb error the second time I start the emulator.

I read that this can be caused by another exception, but I checked a other code and I didnt find anything

```
Button btnentrar = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.createlist);

        btnentrar.Click += delegate
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(listeditorclass));
        };
```

//activity:

```
    private List<string> mItems;
    private ListView mListView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.listeditor);
        mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);

        mItems = new List<string>();
        mItems.Add("Milch");
        mItems.Add("Brot");
        mItems.Add("Apfel");

        MyListViewAdapter adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItems);

        mListView.Adapter = adapter;}
```

also I dont know the diffrents between AppCompatActivity and a normal activity. So general the user should see when he clicks on the button the new view (createlist) with my list.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't used anonymous delegates on Xamarin before, that's a cool thing. Try using an intent and passing the `Context`:

```
    btnentrar.Click += delegate
    {
        StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(listeditorclass)));
    };
```